# how make 2 mountpoints from ices2 (icecast)

Tags: streaming, icecast

How I can make more than 1 mountpoints from one `ices-playlist.xml`?
I try to write:

```html
<ices>

<stream>
<param name="file">rock.txt</param>
</stream>

<stream>
<param name="file">pop.txt</param>
</stream>

</ices>
```

When I check in `icecast`, I have 2 Mountpoints.
But both of them play the second stream.

Please tell me what have I done wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to just start two instances of ices with different configs, one for each mountpoint you need.